# Data binding doesn't work XAML C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF form and I am looking to bind the deserialized json data to a datagrid on UI. But here I am am not able to see the values in my data grid on the UI.

```
JSON response:
Firstly, my json response is in the below format:
{
    "results":
        [
           {"type": "upload", "status": "new","data": {"uuid":"f7e98"},"device_id": "123"},
           {"type": "upload", "status": "new","data": {"uuid":"f8fc1"},"device_id": "456"}, 
           {"type": "upload", "status": "new","data": {"uuid":"fgff1"},"device_id": "678"},
           {"type": "upload", "status": "new","data": {"uuid":"yuki1"},"device_id": "786"},
           {"type": "upload", "status": "new","data": {"uuid":"rtyi1"},"device_id": "654"}
        ]
}
```

**Classes:**

```
public class UploadStatusList
{
    public List<UploadStatus> results;
}
public class UploadStatus
{
    public string type {get;set;}
    public string status {get;set;}
    public string device_id {get;set;}
    public Data data {get;set;}
}
public class Data
{
    public string uuid {get;set;}
}
```

Here is my Main window.xaml.cs
    **MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Dependency Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty actionListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("actionList", typeof(ObservableCollection<UploadStatusList>),
            typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    // .NET Property wrapper
    public ObservableCollection<UploadStatusList> actionList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<UploadStatusList>)GetValue(actionListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(actionListProperty, value); }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Code Block for httpwebRequest here
        //JSON Response String 
        string json = stringbuilder.ToString();

        //Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Deserialize<UploadStatusList>(json) returns null for me here,so using Javascript serializer. No idea why !? 
        UploadStatusList list = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<UploadStatusList>(json);
        foreach (var item in list.results)
        {
            Debug.Print("id: {0}, name: {1}", item.status, item.device_id);
        }
    }
}
```

The below is my Main Window.XAML ... I am new to xaml so unsure if I missed anything
    **MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<TabItem x:Name="UploadList" Header="Upload List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="77" Margin="-2,-2,0,2">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="124*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="107*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Refresh" Margin="14,40,0,361" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" Click="Button_Click"/>

                    <DataGrid Margin="14,79,10,58" x:Name="Access_DataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding actionList.results}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="status" Binding="{Binding status}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="device id" Binding="{Binding device_id}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="type" Binding="{Binding type}" />
           </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
```

Comment: You never set DP `actionList`. Moreover, no need to create it a DP if not binding it from anywhere.

Comment: see the following link for better understanding the binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Answer (score 0):

You doing all right but just need add ElemmentName in Binding in ItemSource or use DataContext.

```
   <Window x:Name="mainWindow".....>
       <... ItemsSource="{Binding actionList.results, ElementName=mainWindow}".....
```

Comment: in code behind you forgot `actionList.Add(list)`. Sorry, i removed your comment.

Comment: and you use list (`actionList`). You have some objects in `actionList` or just one (creates in `mainWindow constructor`). If one object you just need change type actionList to  `public UploadStatusList actionList...` and in code `actionList=list`.